# Detect msvc standard library

Tags: c, visual-c++

How can I reliably detect msvc standard library via preprocessor?

Not msvc compiler with checking _MSC_VER but another compiler utilizing this library?

I'm looking for specific preprocessor macro like `__MINGW32__` in mingw , `__MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR` in mingw-w64

This just academic question.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to detect this in some compiled object? (.lib, .dll, .so, .o, .exe, whatever)

Comment: Are you talking about cases like mingw-gcc, which creates executables linked against MSVCRT.DLL ?

Comment: Since this is just an academic question I suggest you just drop it. There's no reliable way (that I know of) to do what you want. And why would you want to in the first place? Compilers and their standard libraries are fairly tightly coupled - don't try to use one with the other...

Comment: The usual approach to detecting *peculiar* library behavior is autotools' `autoconf` -- a precompilation step compiles and runs test code which detects the peculiar behavior, a header file is written out which defines macros indicating which behaviors were detected, and the application code includes that auto-generated header.

Comment: i asking about specific preprocessor macro like `__MINGW32__` in mingw , `__MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR` in mingw-w64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't compile the msvc libraries with another compiler, they depend upon msvc compiler behaviors and defines.

Secondly, there isn't anything in every msvc standard library header that you could use to test against. Even if there was it would be implementation defined and may also be defined by another standard library implementation.

That said `#include <iostream>` is about as close to universal as it gets. You could look through this file for a unique enough define that you could key off of. For example `_IOSTREAM_`.

Comment: clang able use msvc library but with some specific flags, trying emulate msvc compiler. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html

Comment: if here no common solution, then it is better way.

Comment: So you're trying to decide which compiler is using the libraries? If so then `_MSC_VER` is exactly what you want, it's defined by the compiler not the standard implementation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Comment: no, i want detect which headers used, not compiler. i dont want _MSC_VER.

Comment: So it sounds as though your reason for doing that would be because you are using a makefile which may and may not be using the msvc. If that's the case perhaps you could use your makefile to pass in a define?

Comment: yeah, it is build script used with msvc  or gcc or clang with different standard libraries. if here no solution for detecting msvc standard library then i should choose another way.

Comment: @RedSkotina Essentially yes, you'll need to choose another way. There is not a universal define in the libraries that you could key off of. But again I'd stress that, something knows what library you're using as it's fed to the compiler. Whether that's you or a build script you can also pass in your own `#define`s.